# Linking XCTestCase target with CocoaPods

Tags: ios, unit-testing, cocoapods, xctest

I'm trying to set up a new test target for an existing app. Currently I'm getting the following errors when I try to build the test target:

"Cannot find interface declaration for AFHTTPRequestOperationManager"

Plus three others related to AFNetworking classes not being found. I've added this to the top of my podfile:

```
link_with ['AppBoarder','AppBoarder Tests']
```

and run pod install. I've also included libPods.a to my 'Link binary with Libraries' section of the test target to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: The issue here might be the space. You might try escaping it with `\`?

Comment: I don't think I understand.. a double single quote is the escape sequence for cocoapods? What should the string be if I'm escaping with ''?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry my comment didn't render how I expected it to. I was saying try a backslash `\\`

Comment: No beans on the backslash, I've also tried 'AppBoarder_Tests' and 'AppBoarder-Tests' with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Another forehead slapping moment... The link_with plus including the .a appears to be working. Turns out I have been utilizing the -prefix.pch file in my main target. So for the test target I also need to include things like AFNetworking.h in the test targets -prefix.pch file in order for the target to build correctly.